# Trouble reading .csv files in C++

Tags: c++, csv

I am working on a project where I intend on connecting to a database, grabbing a .csv file, reading it, manipulating the data and then returning it back to the database. Fairly simple and straight forward but I am still learning so if any one could point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it. Right now I have a simple program that is trying to read a .csv file and return the values to me printed on the console. I have been trying to find some good online resources for this but have came up short. Here is my code for what I have stumbled through so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{

int loop = 1;

while(loop = 1)
{

cout << "Welcome! " << endl;

ifstream myfile;

myfile.open ("..\\ Source\External\\ Sample.csv", ifstream::in);
```

The real path to this file is C:\Documents and Settings\RHatfield\My Documents\C++\Product Catalog Creator\Source\External\Sample.csv

```
while (myfile.good())
cout << (char) myfile.get();

myfile.close();
system("PAUSE");

return 0;
}


}
```

Now the issue is it does not print the values so I do not know that they are properly being captured. I have a feeling it is my file path but that's the only way I can find to write it without it throwing errors. I think it's something with the spaces in the file path but I can't seem to find another way to make it work. I am not looking for a handout and this is not homework or just regular work. I am trying to learn and having trouble teaching myself so if someone knows what the issue is and can help me fix it or even point me to a relevant article online would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are right, it is the spaces. What happens when you delete the spaces?

Comment: 19:18 C:\Documents and Settings\RHatfield\My Documents\C++\Product Catalog Creator\Source\ProductCatalogCreator\ProductCatalog0.0.0.2.cpp [Warning] unknown escape sequence '\D'  I get the same error for every wrong letter where there should be a space

Comment: Seems you're not quoting every `\\` correctly.

Comment: You need to either put two \ characters in between each path element, or put one / character. So, try either `"..\\Source\\External\\Sample.csv"` or `"../Source/External/Sample.csv"`.

Comment: By the way, is your program different from the one you pasted above? It is hard to imagine how you get an error message about `\D` when your string doesn't have any `D` in it at all.

Comment: Im sorry I tested that on the full path the d being documents and settings. I noted the full path in the middle of the code snippet.

Comment: Thanks guys that worked. The spaces were fine I just needed to change the way the file path was written using forward slashes! ->myfile.open ("C:/Documents and Settings/RHatfield/My Documents/C++/Product Catalog Creator/Source/External/Sample.csv", ifstream::in);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code.  I think the problem was you were making an assignment statement in the `while` condition statement.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
   cout << "Welcome! " << endl;

   ifstream myfile;

   myfile.open ("C:\\Documents and Settings\\RHatfield\\My Documents\\C++\\Product Catalog Creator\\Source\\External\\Sample.csv", ifstream::in);
   while (myfile.good())
      cout << (char) myfile.get();

   myfile.close();
   system("PAUSE");

   return 0;
}
```